# Unable to combine functions in to one file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions, one to show a gallery of images and one for a smooth scroll up icon. The problem is when I use them separately, both of them works. But when I put them in the same file only the first one works. I can t figure out the problem. I am using jquery-2.0.3
Here is my Code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.demo li').picEyes();
  // Caching the Scroll Top Element
  //    console.log("function move to top");  
  var ScrollButton = $("#scroll");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    //  console.log($(this).scrollTop());

    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {
      ScrollButton.show()
    } else {
      ScrollButton.hide();
    }
  });

  // Click On Button To Scroll To Top Of The Page
  ScrollButton.click(function() {
    $("html,body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
  });
});
```

the code of picEyes function:

```
    (function($){
$.fn.picEyes = function(){
    var $obj = this;
    var num,zg = $obj.length - 1;
    var win_w = $(window).width();
    var win_h = $(window).height();
    var eyeHtml = '<div class="picshade"></div>'
        +'<a class="pictures_eyes_close" href="javascript:;"></a>'
        +'<div class="pictures_eyes">'
        +'<div class="pictures_eyes_in">'
        +'<img src="" />'
        +'<div class="next"></div>'
        +'<div class="prev"></div>'
        +'</div>'
        +'</div>'
        +'<div class="pictures_eyes_indicators"></div>';
    $('body').append(eyeHtml);
    $obj.click(function() {
        $(".picshade").css("height", win_h);
        var n = $(this).find("img").attr('src');
        $(".pictures_eyes img").attr("src", n);
        num = $obj.index(this);
        popwin($('.pictures_eyes'));
    });
    $(".pictures_eyes_close,.picshade,.pictures_eyes").click(function() {
        $(".picshade,.pictures_eyes,.pictures_eyes_close,.pictures_eyes_indicators").fadeOut();
        $('body').css({'overflow':'auto'});
    });
    $('.pictures_eyes img').click(function(e){
        stopPropagation(e);
    });
    $(".next").click(function(e){
        if(num < zg){
            num++;
        }else{
            num = 0;
        }
        var xx = $obj.eq(num).find('img').attr("src");
        $(".pictures_eyes img").attr("src", xx);
        stopPropagation(e);
        popwin($('.pictures_eyes'));
    });
    $(".prev").click(function(e){
        if(num > 0){
            num--;
        }else{
            num = zg;
        }
        var xx = $obj.eq(num).find('img').attr("src");
        $(".pictures_eyes img").attr("src", xx);
        stopPropagation(e);
        popwin($('.pictures_eyes'));
    });
    function popwin(obj){
        $('body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
        var Pwidth = obj.width();
        var Pheight = obj.height();
        obj.css({left:(win_w - Pwidth)/2,top:(win_h - Pheight)/2}).show();
        $('.picshade,.pictures_eyes_close').fadeIn();
        indicatorsList();
    }
    function updatePlace(obj){
        var Pwidth = obj.width();
        var Pheight = obj.height();
        obj.css({left:(win_w - Pwidth)/2,top:(win_h - Pheight)/2});
    }
    function indicatorsList(){
        var indHtml = '';
        $obj.each(function(){
            var img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
            indHtml +='<a href="javascript:;"><img src="'+img+'"/></a>';
        });
        $('.pictures_eyes_indicators').html(indHtml).fadeIn();
        $('.pictures_eyes_indicators a').eq(num).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
        $('.pictures_eyes_indicators a').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
            var xx = $(this).find('img').attr("src");
            $(".pictures_eyes img").attr("src", xx);
            updatePlace($('.pictures_eyes'));
        });
    }
    function stopPropagation(e) {
        e = e || window.event;  
        if(e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation();  
        } else {  
            e.cancelBubble = true;
        }  
    }
}
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: from where you got `ScrollButton`? is somewhere you define/created it? In current code i am unable to see

Comment: Did you mean to comment out `var ScrollButton = $("#scroll");` ? its kinda necessary for your code to work

Comment: No It is not commented. It was a mistake while copying the code. The problem still here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the call of picEyes function outside of the main function and somehow worked !

Answer (score 1):

You should add click event handler, when DOM will be ready, do like this:-

```
   $(function () {
      $('.demo li').picEyes();

    // Caching the Scroll Top Element
    //    console.log("function move to top");  
    //var ScrollButton =ScrollButton.click 

    var ScrollButton = $("#scroll")

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        //  console.log($(this).scrollTop());

        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {
            ScrollButton.show()
        } else {
            ScrollButton.hide();
        }

    });

    // Click On Button To Scroll To Top Of The Page
    ScrollButton.click(function () {
        $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet both scripts have own  ScrollButton element, and while gallery is loaded it owerwrites behaviour of other ScrollButton element.

Comment: I thought about that but found nothing. I will add the code of picEyes function, may be you can help.